# More pythonic implementation for continuously looping through list

Tags: python

I have a list of tokens that I want to use for accessing an API.  I'd like to always be able to select the next token in the list for use, and when the end of the list is reached, start over.

I have this now, which works, but I find it to be pretty messy and unreadable.

```
class tokenz:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tokens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
        self.num_tokens = len(tokens)
        self.last_token_used = 0

    def select_token(self):
        if self.last_token_used == 0:
            self.last_token_used += 1
            return self.tokens[0]
        elif self.last_token_used < (self.num_tokens - 1):
            self.last_token_used += 1
            return self.tokens[self.last_token_used - 1]
        elif self.last_token_used == (self.num_tokens -1):
            self.last_token_used = 0
            return self.tokens[self.num_tokens - 1]
```

Any thoughts on making this more pythonic?

Comment: any reason why they have to be consumed in an ordered manner as opposed to just grabbing the next viable one regardless of position?

Comment: Why not iterate over `itertools.cycle(tokens)`?

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy for rate limiting purposes, i'd say it would be easiest to call them in order? if one of them is called 51 times and another is called 49 within a timeframe, i'd hit a limit.

Comment: that doesn't matter if you write a function that checks the `response.status_code` from the api and just grabs the next viable token.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy wouldn't i want to avoid writing that logic if i could guarantee what i wouldn't hit a limit?

Comment: sure, but tokens also expire, your logic would have to account for that as well

Comment: @metersk: Wouldn't it be better to auto-generate tokens on the fly and save them with a timestamp?

Comment: they are autogenerated for each time the job is run, which is once an hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [itertools.cycle()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to get a generator that repeats a list of items infinitely.

```
In [13]: tokens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

In [14]: import itertools

In [15]: infinite_tokens = itertools.cycle(tokens)

In [16]: [next(infinite_tokens) for _ in range(13)]
Out[16]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

If you really want to make your posted code simpler, use modular arithmetic.

```
self.last_token_used = (self.last_token_used + 1) % len(self.tokens)
```

Also, you can use negative indexes in Python lists, so your `if` statements are unnecessary:

```
In [26]: for n in range(len(tokens)):
    ...:     print('{}: tokens[{}] = {}'.format(n, n-1, tokens[n-1]))
    ...:
0: tokens[-1] = e
1: tokens[0] = a
2: tokens[1] = b
3: tokens[2] = c
4: tokens[3] = d
```

And then your code becomes:

```
class tokenz:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tokens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
        self.num_tokens = len(self.tokens)
        self.last_token_used = 0

    def select_token(self):
        self.last_token_used = (self.last_token_used + 1) % self.num_tokens
        return self.tokens[self.last_token_used - 1]
```

Comment: this looks perfect